# Are the Xenomorphs intelligent enough to commandeer spacecraft?

Tags: alien-franchise

Are the Xenomorphs intelligent enough to commandeer a spacecraft they overwhelm, or do they just go along for the ride?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  The rolling, flaming destruction of the commandeered dropship in *Aliens* demonstrated poor piloting skills at best and a complete lack of situational awareness at worst.  If the alien were intelligent it would have waited until the dropship landed safely before turning both pilots into salsa.

Comment: Worst. Hitchhiker. Ever.

Comment: Cute, but I don't think this is definitive proof. It's not clear that the xenomorph that boarded the dropship ever tried to commandeer the ship. Its goal/job could have simply been to strand the team on the planet. The fact that some human hijackers have crashed planes as well doesn't mean that humans are incapable of flying planes.

Answer (score 12):

I would have to say "no", they are not intelligent enough to control/pilot a ship. They are shown to have *some* degree of intelligence when they interact with basic machinery, for example:

- The Queen figuring out how to use an elevator in [Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/).
- A xenomorph pushing a button to blast someone with gas in [Alien: Resurrection](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118583/).

But these interactions are tantamount to simply pushing a button. So, if they ever commandeered the [Heart of Gold](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_Gold), well, we're all in trouble:

[image: Hopefully, they'll be distracted by the tasty mice!]

Comment: That would be most [improbable](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Improbability_Drive)

Comment: Be careful, the Picture Police will get you!

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say, "yes" or at least we do not know. I think that one comic or novelization indicates that queens can be more intelligent than most humans.

But the incredible flexibility of alien reproduction, the fact that the Ripley clone retains memories of the original, implies to me that basically all bets are off and an alien who not only can speak English but can pilot a ship or even manage to overcome its genetic urges to reproduce could show up in some future version (if it has not already happened in a comic, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I say eventually they would be able to pilot spacecraft. Each new generation of Xenos is smarter than the last so in the far future they would probably have evolved enough to be able to pilot or even build spacecraft, possibly weapons too and with enough time they would be on par with the Yaut'ja.  Its really simple guys. they just need to evolve more just as the Humans did.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you provide any supporting references from the material to support this opinion ?  Ex - 'Each new generation .. is smarter'.  At least one example supporting that would be good.  You'll find the community isn't very forgiving of answers that express only an opinion without supporting it.  You might it helpful to read the [FAQs](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help).  Didn't downvote since you're new to the site.